# Code Error 307 temporary redirect in Apache Camel

Tags: java, http, apache-camel, quarkus, http-status-code-307

Good afternoon, I am currently working with Apache Camel and Quarkus, I have the following error when calling a Web Service in SOAP, it responds with an http code 307
​

```
org.apache.camel.http.base.HttpOperationFailedException: HTTP operation failed invoking http://10.164.232.12:8001/ with statusCode: 307, redirectLocation: http://10.164.232.12:8001/002245245
```

This error happened to me in postman and what I did was enable Automatically follow redirects so that it returned the code 200:

**Before:**

[image: Este]

**After:**

[image]

How can I do in Apache Camel to be able to receive the response in code http 200?

My last code before calling the WS is the following:

RestRoute

```
public class RestRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    @ConfigProperty(name = "client.ubd.loginConnector")
    String udbLgiCommand;

    @ConfigProperty(name = "path.openapi")
    String pathOpenapi;

    @ConfigProperty(name = "descripcion.servicio")
    String descriptionService;

    private IGetCurrentDateTime getCurrentDateTime;

    public RestRoute() {
        getCurrentDateTime = new GetCurrentDateTime();
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-4"));
    }
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        BeanDate beanDate= new BeanDate();
        getContext().getRegistry().bind("BeanDate", beanDate);

        restConfiguration().bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json).dataFormatProperty("json.in.disableFeatures","FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES")
                .apiContextPath(pathOpenapi)
                .apiProperty("api.title","UdbLoginConnector")
                .apiProperty("api.description",descriptionService)
                .apiProperty("api-version","1.0.0")
                .apiProperty("cors","true");
        rest("/api/")
                .produces("application/json")
                .consumes("application/json")
                .post("/udbLoginConnector")
                .type(UdbLoginConnectorJsonReq.class)
                .param().name("UdbLoginConnectorJsonReq").type(RestParamType.body).description("Parametros de Entradas")
                .required(true)
                .endParam()
                .outType(UdbLoginConnectorJsonResp.class)
                .param().name("UdbLoginConnectorJsonResp").type(RestParamType.body).description("Parametros de Salidas")
                .required(true)
                .endParam().to("direct:pipeline");

                from("direct:pipeline")
                        .doTry()
                            /*.to("bean-validator:validateUdbLoginConnectorJsonReq") */
                            .process(new UdbLoginConnectorProcessorReq())
                            .log("["+"${bean:BeanDate.getCurrentDateTime()}"+"] "+ "Datos de Entrada del MS:  ${exchangeProperty[bodyRq]}")
                            .process(new UdbLgiCommandProcessorReq())
                            .log("["+"${bean:BeanDate.getCurrentDateTime()}"+"] "+ "Datos de Entrada del WS de K2:  ${exchangeProperty[wsRq]}")
                            .to(udbLgiCommand)
                            .log("["+"${bean:BeanDate.getCurrentDateTime()}"+"] "+ "Datos de Salida del WS de K2:  ${body}")
                        .endDoTry();
    }
}
```

**UdbLgiCommandProcessorReq**

```
@Slf4j
public class UdbLgiCommandProcessorReq implements Processor{

    private IUdbLgiCommandRequestMapping requestMapping;

    public UdbLgiCommandProcessorReq() {
        requestMapping = new UdbLgiCommandRequestMappingImpl();
    }
    
    @SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation", "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        
        UdbLoginConnectorJsonReq udbLoginConnectorJsonReq = (UdbLoginConnectorJsonReq) exchange.getProperty("udbLoginConnectorJsonReq");
        /*log.info("Request Json Entrada: "+udbLoginConnectorJsonReq.toString()); */
        EnvelopeRq envelopeRq = requestMapping.toRequest(udbLoginConnectorJsonReq);
        String xmlWsRq = new GenericXml().toXmlString(envelopeRq);
        /*log.info("Transformacion a XML "+xmlWsRq); */
        exchange.setProperty("wsRq", xmlWsRq.replaceAll("[\n\t\r]", ""));
        exchange.getOut().setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/xml");
        exchange.getOut().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, "POST");
        exchange.getOut().setBody(xmlWsRq);
    }
}
```